Selenium/Python - By.CSS_SELECTOR returns "An invalid or illegal selector was specified"
Hi y'all I been trying to learn Selenium with python by following this beginner course:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7VZsCCnptM&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org
Because it is several years old some of the syntax has changed and the webpage they use for the tutorial has changed as well but so far I was still able to get it working and understand what I was doing wrong or when something had changed and I needed to look for new documentation.
But I finally hit a wall here.
The task was for the program to select two date inside a calendar and the html for that section doesn't seem to have changed a lot from 2021 but I can't get it to work (Last def at the end of main)
main
import booking.constants as cons
import time
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

# IGNORE from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


class Booking(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, driver_path=r"C:\SeleniumDrivers", teardown=False):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        self.teardown = teardown
        os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path
        super(Booking, self).__init__()
        self.implicitly_wait(15)
        self.maximize_window()

        # ↑ Chrome setup

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self.teardown:
            self.quit()
        # ↑ quits browser after running

    def land_first_page(self):
        self.get(cons.BASE_URL)
        # ↑ define action: redirect to BASE_URL

    def change_currency(self, currency=None):
        currency_element = self.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-testid="header-currency-picker-trigger"]')
        # ↑ Finds the currency selector button
        currency_element.click()

        sltd_currency_element = self.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-testid="selection-item"]')
        # ↑ Makes a list of all buttons with data-testid="selection-item" (all currencies)
        for sltd_currency in sltd_currency_element:
            # ↓ Checks which item in the above list contains a partial pass with currency
            if currency in sltd_currency.text:
                sltd_currency.click()
                time.sleep(2)
                break  # DON'T FORGET TO BREAK THE MF 'FOR'

    def close_ini_popup(self):
        ini_popup_element = self.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[aria-label="Dismiss sign-in info."]')
        ini_popup_element.click()

    # ↑ Closes the initial popup asking you to login

    def select_place_to_go(self, place_to_go=None):
        search_field = self.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'eb46370fe1')
        search_field.clear()
        search_field.send_keys(place_to_go)
        search_result = self.find_element(By.ID, 'autocomplete-result-0')
        search_result.click()
        time.sleep(5)

    # ↑ Finds the destination field, clears it, fills it and selects the first result

    def select_dates(self, ci_date, co_date):
        check_in_element = self.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'data-date="{ci_date}')
        check_in_element.click()

        check_out_element = self.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'data-date="{co_date}')
        check_out_element.click()
    # ↑ Selects check in/out dates - YYYY/MM/DD


constant
BASE_URL = "https://www.booking.com/"

deploy
from booking.booking import Booking

with Booking() as bot:
    bot.land_first_page()
    bot.close_ini_popup()
    #bot.change_currency(currency='AUD')
    bot.select_place_to_go('Buenos Aires')
    bot.select_dates(ci_date='2024-05-19', co_date='2024-06-24')

while(True):
    pass  # lazy way to prevent browser from closing as soon as the program finishes


So far I tried looking for other CSS_Selectors for the dates, doing a for similar to the one I used for currency, using ec.presence_of_element_located() but no luck

I was referencing [def select_dates] which is the last defined process in main.py, also the one that I'm having issues with.

Your CSS selector is going to be data-time=2024-05-19. That means "data-time=2024-05-19" is expected to be a valid CSS Selector. I don't think it is.

I'm trying to reference a single td from the page, all td in that page share the same class so I can't use that and the only element that isn't shared with other dates are the data-time and aria-label from this span that is a child of that td
19
it's highly probable I'm doing something wrong, I also tried changing the code to:
f'td[data-date="ci_date"]'
but that didn't work either even tho it is the code used in the course

I double checked and it had written data-time instead of data-date. That being said I still get the "An invalid or illegal selector was specified"

An example of an element you are looking for is
<span data-date="2024-05-01" ...>
    <span>1</span>
</span>

A valid CSS selector to find that SPAN would be
[data-date='2024-05-01']

but your code is producing
data-date="2024-05-01"

which is missing the brackets, []s.
You can update your code to the below to fix it
def select_dates(self, ci_date, co_date):
    self.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'[data-date="{ci_date}]').click()
    self.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'[data-date="{co_date}]').click()

